# Pygame type error with Rect function arguments

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting this error

```
File "main.py", line 48, in update
    self.rect = self.rect.move((self.dirx, self.diry))
TypeError: argument must contain two numbers
```

self is a sprite object that has a rect attribute. In my game, I am trying to move these sprites around by using:

```
self.rect = self.rect.move((self.dirx, self.diry))
```

dirx and diry are simply ints between 1 and 3(indicating speed).
I have asked multiple peers, but nobody has been able to give me feeback.

EDIT
So what was happening was that dirx and diry were getting too large to be considered ints in another method

Comment: I don't know Pygame, but shouldn't the args to `rect.move` be 2 separate numbers, not a tuple?

Comment: Please, verify that self.dirx and self.diry are both numbers (try debugger or prints)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was incrementing dirx and diry too much in other places and I think they go too large, and it automatically converted to a long.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing two numbers as two arguments instead of a tuple as shown in the official docs:

```
move(self.dirx, self.diry)
```

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move

Comment: I see where I could have gone wrong, but I tried it that way, and I'm getting the same error: File "main.py", line 48, in update
    self.rect = self.rect.move(self.dirx, self.diry)
TypeError: argument must contain two numbers

Comment: @MehulGhosal So they aren't numbers. Check what type of objects `self.dirx` and `self.diry` are. I suspect that they're strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning it as a tuple you need to just return the numbers. Try: `self.rect = self.rect.move(self.dirx, self.diry)`